# umbraco cms not reflecting changes made directly to files on disk

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have some templates that I have edited directly with sublime text or visual studio (doesn't matter).  The UI for the Umbraco CMS will not reflect these changes and therefore the website is not rendering the changes either.

Is there a setting / trick to force Umbraco to pick up these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. close browser
2. restart IIS
3. if it still doesn't work
4. create new file in Umbraco, not on the disk
5. copy old content intonew file

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting Ctrl-F5 because a lot of caching is happening inside Umbraco. And with the new AngularJS backoffice which is very nice but also a pain in the ass with this kind of things.

Comment: yeah, clearing the cache is usually a first step, not sure what all I tried at this point though